# Run application after receiving information from the server

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node js application. I want the express web server to be created when I get a response to a request from the server
I could not solve the problem with Promises but every time I get an unidefind error

The steps are as follows:
1 - send a request and get response
2 - if response has a correct value set config in export.module
3 - start express server with config set from the previous step

thanks

Comment: Which application are you referring here? And How do you run an express server? I didn't quite follow the question, add more details to it.

Comment: You need some sort of server where the request can be handled initially and then execute the process on the other server which you wish to start based on the initial request